# Using Camera on android

Tags: android

In my library project I have the following code to initialize the camera, and start previewing.

```
public class CameraView  {

private SurfaceView preview;
private SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
private Camera camera;
private boolean activeCamera;
private boolean cameraConfigured;
private Activity activity;
private final static int NINTY_DEGREES = 90; 


public CameraView(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;

    View rootView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_cameraview, null);
    preview = (SurfaceView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    cameraConfigured = false;
}

private void initializeCamera(int w, int h) {
    if(camera != null && previewHolder.getSurface() != null) {

        try 
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Camera: ", e.getMessage());
        }


        if(!cameraConfigured) {
            Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(w, h, params);

            if(size != null) {
                params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                cameraConfigured = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void startCamera() {
    camera = Camera.open();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
}

public void stopCamera() {
    stopPreviewingOnDisplay();
}

public void takePicture() {
    View rootView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_cameraview, null);
    Button capture = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("CameraView: ", "Capture button pressed!");
        }
    });
}

private void startPreviewingOnDisplay() {
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(NINTY_DEGREES);
        camera.startPreview();
        activeCamera = true;
    }
}

private void stopPreviewingOnDisplay() {
    if(camera != null && activeCamera) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        activeCamera = false;
    }
}

private SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        initializeCamera(width, height);
        startPreviewingOnDisplay();
        Log.d("CameraView: ", "SurfaceChanged");
    }
};

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int w, int h, Camera.Parameters params) {

    Camera.Size result = null;

    for(Camera.Size size : params.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if(size.width < w && size.height <= h) {
            if(result == null) {
                result = size;
            }
            else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if(newArea > resultArea)
                    result = size;
            }
        }
    }       
    return(result);
}
```

}

The usage of this class:

```
public class History extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                ......
       camera = new CameraView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() { 
       super.onResume();
       Log.i("History.class", "onResume called!");
       camera.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       camera.stopCamera();
    }
}
```

I've debugged the code, and I notice that the camera object is being intitalized, but there is nothing appearing on the screen, it should have previewed the camera. Could anyone see whats wrong with this approach?

Thanks.

Comment: did you add camera permission in manifest file ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Otherwise an exception would be thrown.